# Adding class to SlickJS when slide is in center mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to a slide when it is in center using [slickjs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel. I check for the class `.slick-center` and `data-slick-index` attribute to determine when the slide is in center based on its index. My `if` statement is set up as follows:

```
var highlightDiv = document.getElementById('highlight');
var slideIndex = highlightDiv.getAttribute('data-slick-index');


if ((highlightDiv.className == 'slick-center') || (slideIndex == 1)) {
    $('#highlight').addClass('red');
}
```

As you can see in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz1osp8x/), the class gets added on page load. The `if` statement does not work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1) Your if statement does work. On page load the index is equal to 1 so it is executed immediately.

2) You need to put your code in a function callback for whenever the slide occurs. Otherwise it will only run on page load. The documentation suggests you do it like this

```
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

3) Your first condition in your if statement is flawed because highlightDiv.className returns multiple classes like so `boxes slick-slide slick-active`.

## Improvement

```
var highlight = $('#highlight');
$('.stack').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){

    if (currentSlide == 1) {
        highlight.addClass('red');
    }
    else {
        highlight.removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks AR7. But the 'swipe' event only fires when you click and drag the carousel, but not when you click on the next slide.

Comment: I didn't know but even still, you can fire it on `beforeChange` then or `afterChange` I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've gotten it work somewhat: http://jsfiddle.net/bz1osp8x/1/. How can I remove the class when slide #2 is not in center?

Comment: I guess `toggleClass` does the trick instead of `addClass`. But if there's a better solution, I am happy to hear it.

Comment: @kolor I edited my answer. That's a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I always found just using the index of the slide not to be sufficient, because of cloned slide elements. So in addition:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange',function(event,slick,currentslide){
    $(this).find('.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned):eq('+currentslide+')').addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: This adds class on all slides when they come to the center. I would like to only add it to slide #2, and then remove it when slide is changed.